# Changing the selected text/value of dropdownlist dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a html page with a dropdown list

```
        <div id="Tester">
            <div id="ReportingPeriod">
            <label for="ReportPeriod">Reporting Period:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlperiod", Model.GetReportingPeriodInfo.Reportingperiodselectlist, Model.GetReportingPeriodInfo.Selectedreportingperiod, new { @class = "sel" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the html that is rendered when the page loads for the dropdown

```
        <div id="ReportingPeriod">
                <label for="ReportPeriod">Reporting Period:</label>
                <select class="sel" id="ddlperiod" name="ddlperiod"><option value="">Select Period</option>
                <option value="1">Apr-16</option>
                <option value="2">Aug-16</option>
                <option value="3">Dec-15</option>
                <option value="4">Dec-16</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

On change of another dropdown I am retrieving a set of data from the database. I just didnt include the dropdown in the code

```
            //select Items on dropdown and populate the page
             $('#ddlstatusdate').on('change', function () {
                 var obj = $('.ddlprojects').not(':hidden');
                 var selectedPrjId = obj.val();
                 var things = $('#ddlstatusdate').val();

                 $.get('@Url.Action("GetNoteResult", "Home")', { 'selectedData': things, 'selectedProjectId': selectedPrjId }, function (result) {
                      $('#Tester').html(result);
                     //set value of dropdown to what was retrieved from database
                     //got a value of 3 from database
                 });

            });
```

Que: I will like to change the selected text of the dropdown once I get this value from the database.
For example If I get 3 back from the database I want to set the dropdown to have a value of 3 meaning text of Dec-15 will
be selected in the dropdown. Is this possible?

Comment: `$('#ddlperiod').val(3);` ?

Comment: `$('#ddlperiod').val(result);` will select "Dec-15" if `result = 3`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will try it now. Appreciate your contribution.